# Python Pandas DataFrame: Split variable text column and then count

Tags: pandas

I have a column in my database with each cell having a list of e-mail addresses separated by commas. Each cell has different numbers of e-mail addresses. I am trying to figure out which e-mail address is most common overall.

I was thinking I would combine all these cells into one cell, and then split thm by comma, and then use the Counter function to find the most used e-mail address. But I am getting stuck at the first step. Is there a way to combine everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In[0] import pandas as pd

In[1] data = pd.Series(["abc@def.com,pqr@def.com", "abc@def.com", "abc@def.com,xyz@def.com,pqr@def.com"])

In[3]: data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Emails"])

In[4]: pd.Series(data.Emails.str.split(',', expand=True).values.ravel()).mode().values[0]
Out[4]: 'abc@def.com'
```